# disabling constraints will affect indexes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, indexing

I have to migrate records from one db to another db. It involves nearly 200+ tables. For migrating records I use `exp/imp` feature of oracle.

To avoid constraint violation errors I disable all constraints before importing data. Once done will enable constraints. And in export I am not exporting source db indexes.

So, my questions here are

1. When I disable constraints respective indexes will be disabled?
2. It won't do any indexing at all?
3. Will index rebuilds it indexes when I enable constraints after importing data?

Answer (score 3):

If you're on 10g or above use data pump, and these will no longer be issues that you have to address.

Data pump import and export allow much greater control over the type of object to include, so you can choose not to import indexes if you do not want them: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10701/dp_import.htm

Comment: You mean even I disable constraints those indexes will be processed while importing data using impdp? Because I don't need indexes of source DB as they are completely different from target DB.